# XAML sem o previewer ou designer - Visual Studio

Tags: xamarin, xaml, xamarin-studio, x64, xamarin-forms

Estou usando o Visual Studio 2015 Community com o Xamarin, e percebi que ao editar o XAML em modo designer (Shift + F7) não consigo visualizar o preview dele, pois é aberta outra janela com o mesmo fonte. Não consigo ainda ver sua renderização no Xamarin.Forms Previewer.

O projeto está devidamente compilado, não há erros, e consigo utilizá-lo no celular, VMs Android, e demais outras plataformas.

Fiz ainda os procedimentos:

- Habilitei Tools > Options > XAML Desginer > Enable XAML Designer, e reiniciei o VS, inclusive variando todas as opções desta tela.
- Acessei View > Other Windows > Xamarin.Forms Previewer (eis a tela abaixo):

  [image: Preview sem a renderização, e aberto o fonte que deveria estar em modo desginer:]
  Considerações adicionais:

  - Uso a versão ESTÁVEL do Xamarin
  - Todos os NuGet packages (os necessários ao funcionamento do projeto, tal como o Xamarin.Forms) estão atualizados
  - Computador recém formado e software instalado
  - SO Windows 10 Enterprise x64, e testada também na versão Pro.

Comment: A versão do Xamarin Forms está atualizada? Você vai precisar da versão 64bits do java instalada.

Comment: Sim, Angelo. E também a versão do Java é x64. A mais atual que havia instalado para fazer este teste foi a jdk1.8.0_121.

Comment: Eu utilizo o Visual Studio 2017, 15.8.0 Preview 1.1 
Ele contém várias melhorias e correções de bugs. Pode ser instalado lado a lado com outra versão. Veja https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/preview/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O preview pelo visual studio 2015 ainda não está funcionando em muitos casos, você pode tentar atualizar o android ndk para uma versão mais recente, e se mesmo assim não funcionar pode utilizar um preview do Gorilla Player.
http://gorillaplayer.com/